# Making normal monadic functions work with the monad transformer equivalent

Tags: parsing, haskell, stack, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to solve the balanced brackets problem. I don't want to do continuous IO, and would rather make a single call to getLine and parse the resulting string. Therefore the function that solves the problem will deal with two different states: The unconsumed part of the input string, and the bracket stack.

I want to set up some functions for manipulating a stack:

```
type Stack = String

pop :: Stack -> (Char,Stack)
pop (x:xs) = (x,xs)

push :: Char -> Stack -> ((),Stack)
push a xs = ((),a:xs)
```

That's all good if I'm operating in the state monad, however I'm operating in the StateT monad

```
balanced :: StateT Stack (State String) Bool
```

I know I've been told not to have duplicate monads in the stack. I'm doing it this way because I like how it simplifies the push and pop definitions.

Two problems:

1. No matter what I do I can't find a way to apply push and pop to the
   Stack contained in the StateT.
2. I have no idea how to call this from the main function

Here's the rest of the code

```
next :: String -> (Maybe Char,String)
next ""     = (Nothing,[])
next (x:xs) = (Just x,xs)

balanced = do
            c <- lift (state next)
            case c of
              Nothing -> return True
              Just c  -> if elem c open 
                         then (push c) >> balanced
                         else if elem c close 
                              then pop >>= \x ->
                                if eq x c
                                then balanced
                                else return False
                              else balanced
          where open  = "<{(["
                close = "])}>"
                eq '(' ')' = True
                eq '{' '}' = True
                eq '<' '>' = True
                eq '[' ']' = True
                eq  _   _  = False
```

Comment: Try using `Reader String` instead of `State String` for the inner monad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that your `push` and `pop` are just ordinary, non-monadic function which you are trying to use in the monadic do-block. You are using `next` correctly, since you call it using the `state` function, but as you probably noticed, `state` only works for the plain `State` monad and not `StateT`.

We can implement a monad transformer version of `state` like this:

```
stateT :: Monad m => (s -> (a, s)) -> StateT s m a
stateT f = do
    (x, s') <- gets f
    put s'
    return x
```

And then use it in the `balanced` function with `push` and `pop`.

```
balanced :: StateT Stack (State String) Bool
balanced = do
            c <- lift (state next)
            case c of
              Nothing -> return True
              Just c  -> if elem c open
                         then (stateT $ push c) >> balanced
                         else if elem c close
                              then stateT pop >>= \x ->
                                if eq x c
                                    then balanced
                                    else return False
                              else balanced
          where open  = "<{(["
                close = "])}>"
                eq '(' ')' = True
                eq '{' '}' = True
                eq '<' '>' = True
                eq '[' ']' = True
                eq  _   _  = False
```

The function is called like this:

```
evalState (evalStateT balanced []) s
```

Where `s` is the initial string and `[]` is the initial stack.